# Why does cout print the ascii value of a char when used with a ternary and int?

Tags: c++, char, cout, ternary

Why does this code produce 42012 instead of *012? I can see that it is converting the asterisk to its ASCII value but why?

```c++
    vector<int> numbers = {-1,0,1,2};
    for(int num: numbers){
        cout << (num == -1 ? '*' : num); //42012
    }

    for(int num: numbers){
        if(num == -1) cout << '*'; //*012
        else cout << num;
    }
```

If I use a normal if else statement it works. Why?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634198/why-does-stdstring-view-create-a-dangling-view-in-a-ternary-expression , the issue is different, the cause is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary expression returns the "common type" of its true part and false part, and the common type between `char` and `int` is `int`, so `'*'` is promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Found a geeks for geeks article on it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-ternary-operator-some-interesting-observations/)